# What's a better way to clean up database, rake task or sql?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I need to clean up some data in mysql DB.For example, delete some records under some conditions. I'm wondering what's the best practice to achieve this? My Web app is written in Rails, I can write some Rake tasks to do the work or I can write some sql directly to achieve this. Which is better? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since it's a Rails app, it seems sensible and natural to create a `rake` task which will live in your Rails application structure. Since you can use ActiveRecord in the `rake` task, it should be easier to write than pure SQL and it would use your existing data model, and use database access patterns you already employ in the rest of your app. This way, if you change anything in the underlying model, you typically wouldn't have to worry about changing the Rake task. SQL you'd have to make sure you manually updated.

Comment: If that is related to the business domain, that this condition can happen again in a certain status of flow then move that to a model function and use Active record queries for clean code. Else you can use rake tasks if its one-time thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's all based on your requirement, if it's a one time clean up and it's not required to happen at any scheduled time then, doing it with `sql` is good. But this cleanup is to be performed many times then I would suggest you to use `rake task`, since they are written once and can be ran `many times` and can be `scheduled` as well using `schedular`.